# Opening WDK Projects results in "One or more errors occurred" message

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, driver, wdk, kmdf

I'm trying to make a Windows kernel driver, but every time I either try to make a new project with KMDF template or open an example driver by Microsoft (like keyboard filter), it doesn't work.

In the case of loading an existing driver project, it "fails to load." Upon reloading it, I get the message box giving me an incredibly descriptive error message: "One or more errors occurred."

I get the same oh-so-descriptive message box when trying to create a new driver project from a template.

How can I get rid of this error message and load/create Windows drivers?

As I'm currently limited to VS 2015 and will not be using VS 2017 anytime soon, the WDK version I have installed is known as "WDK for Windows 10, version 1703" and can be found at [Other WDK Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads).

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30760/unable-to-create-kernel-driver-projects-unable-to.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with visual studio 2015 you can read about  that [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/95626/one-or-more-errors-occurred-enter.html)

So download the updated version VS2015 and you may be able to load and create the new KMDF projects.